# Buildfarm doesn't define the ROS_DISTRO environment variable

Tags: ros, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My package uses the `$ROS_DISTRO` environment variable at configure time for `dh_installudev` and for differences between Indigo and Kinetic. The buildfarm doesn't seem to define `$ROS_DISTRO`.

CMakeLists.txt:
https://bitbucket.org/DataspeedInc/sainsmart_relay_usb/src/0.0.1/CMakeLists.txt?fileviewer=file-view-default#CMakeLists.txt-29

Buildfarm errors:
http://build.ros.org/job/Ibin_uT64__sainsmart_relay_usb__ubuntu_trusty_amd64__binary/1/console
http://build.ros.org/job/Kbin_uX64__sainsmart_relay_usb__ubuntu_xenial_amd64__binary/1/console

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277124/buildfarm-doesn%27t-define-the-ros_distro-environment-variable/) by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1416 on 2017-12-01

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT: UPDATE 2022

We have formalized the solution to getting this environment variable. You should use the [`ros_environment`](https://index.ros.org/p/ros_environment/) package to get these sorts of variables defined and available in your workspace.

---

Old answer:

Yeah, we don't set that in the debian build environment. You can see it for your package here: https://github.com/DataspeedInc-release/sainsmart_relay_usb-release/blob/debian/kinetic/sainsmart_relay_usb/debian/rules.em

You could try extending the template in bloom: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/blob/master/bloom/generators/debian/templates/catkin/rules.em and if that resolves your problem it might be worth considering a pull request. Though I'd like to see if there's a cleaner way to determine the debian package name during the compile, but I can't find anything.

@nuclearsandwich @william FYI

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2017-12-02**:
It looks like it's not necessary to know the debian package name. The simple filename `udev` can be used.
https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver/pull/131
https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver/tree/0.13.4/pointgrey_camera_driver/debian

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you could try adding a direct dependency on `roslib` in your package. As long as `roslib` is installed before building your package it should be set I think because `roslib`'s environment hook set the env variable.

I'm not sure why `roscpp` doesn't transitively depend on `roslib` but `rospy` does, @Dirk Thomas any idea is that's desired/correct or an oversight?

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-12-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2017-12-02**:
Adding a build dependency on `roslib` fixed everything: https://bitbucket.org/DataspeedInc/sainsmart_relay_usb/commits/440931002eb8fdfd008f4c5178da86305cc56bfa